# Switch triangular matrix

Tags: python, numpy, triangular, numpy-ndarray

Is there an easy way to turn around a triangular matrix.

```
import numpy as np
shape=(4,8) 

x3=np.ones(shape) 

for m in range(len(x3)):
    step = (m * int(2)+1) #per step of 2 zeros
    for  n in range(int(step), len(x3[m])):
        x3[m][n] = 0
```

Gives me this matrix:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

I want to switch this to something like this:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Just `x3[:, ::-1]`

Comment: Also, here's another way of doing the whole thing: `np.repeat(np.tri(4, 5), 2, axis=1)[:, -2::-1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.flip` from [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) package does the trick :

```
A = array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
           [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]])

np.flip(A, 1)
#returns what you want : 1 for vertical symetry

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```